# Seperate footer on left and right side of the screen

Tags: html, css

I've got a div with my footer which is absolutely positoned.
When the screen-width is lower than 800 pixels I'd like the last two links of the `<div>` to appear on the right-side of the screen with `right: 2em`.

**How can I achieve this?**

```
<div class="footer">©Example| <a id="imprint">Imprint</a> | <a href="#" >AGB</a> |<a href="#">Privacy</a> | <a href="#">Feedback</a></div>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
.footer {
    position: absolute;
    left: 2em;
    bottom: 2em;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to make a media query so the to right ones will float right when below 800px;

```
@media screen and (max-width:800px) {
    .right {
        float:right;
        margin-left:4px;
    }    
}
```

Here is an example: https://jsfiddle.net/ms90pncr/